# CUDA linking error on OS X El Capitan

Tags: cuda, tensorflow, osx-elcapitan, cudnn

I've been trying to install CUDA and cuDNN for TensorFlow as [instructed](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/os_setup#prepare_environment_for_mac_os_x) on the TensorFlow page. Everything works until I do the following:

```
$ cp -r /usr/local/cuda/samples ~/cuda-samples
$ pushd ~/cuda-samples
$ make
```

I then get the following error:

```
clang++  -rpath /Developer/NVIDIA/CUDA-7.5/lib -L/Developer/NVIDIA/CUDA-7.5/lib -framework CUDA -o clock_nvrtc clock.o  -lnvrtc
ld: framework not found CUDA
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[1]: *** [clock_nvrtc] Error 1
make: *** [0_Simple/clock_nvrtc/Makefile.ph_build] Error 2
```

My question of course is what's causing the error, and how to fix it. I had previously installed CUDA 7.5, and then I installed 8.0. The whole of CUDA (and its installation) is just a black box to me; I'm just trying to get it to work with TensorFlow.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the following in your terminal -

```
xcode-select --install
```

Then try to run `make` again.

Saw the answer on an NVidia forum - https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/628298/cuda-samples-on-mac-os-x-mavericks-10-9-matrixmuldrv/

It's also documented in this Quick Start Guide - http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-quick-start-guide/index.html#axzz4YvZYOZc0

Answer (score 2):

Add the folder containing the folder `CUDA.framework` to the command line as such:

```
-F<folder>
```

It looks like the linker isn't able to find the framework and you have to point it where it is

Comment: The error occurs when I run make, and -F is not an option for make.

Comment: Because it is a compiler flag

Comment: You need to add it to CFLAGS or similar

Comment: When I add -F/Library/Frameworks the error changes to "ld: library not found for -lnvrtc".

Comment: So add also a flag with `-L<somewhere>`, where `<somewhere>` is the place containing `libnvrtc.dylib` or `libnvrtc.a`